# Changing CSS file in YII app doesn't work

Tags: php, css, yii

I am trying to change the styling of the `gridview`, `tableview`, & `detailview`. I found something saying that I should change the `config/main.php` file to this:

```
...
// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
     'widgetFactory'=>array(
        'widgets'=>array(
            'CGridView'=>array(
                'cssFile' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/table_and_grid.css',
            ),

        ),
    ),
...
```

I have removed the assets folder that is generated by the app, but that didn't help. When I load the view, I can see that the css sheet is being loaded into the header of the page, but none of the styling is working. Why? How do I fix?

Comment: What position does your custom css file load? Can you use Web inspector to check the browser's interpretation of your css rules?

Comment: @ragingprodigy It's one of the first to load. And the browser isn't interpreting ANY of the rules, which is the problem.

Comment: i dont think that you need to change main.config for changing style. If you need to change style you can override the functions and properties in base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anything about changing the style of `CGridView` in main config file`(main.php)`, But you can customize `CGridView` styles with bellow parameters:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'SOME ID',
'dataProvider'=>$YOUR_DATA_PROVIDET,
'cssFile'=>'...',
'baseScriptUrl'=>'...',
'filterCssClass'=>'...',
'itemsCssClass'=>'...',
'pagerCssClass'=>'...',
'rowCssClass'=>'...',
'summaryCssClass'=>'...',
));
```

You can change `...` with your own.
for more information you can check `CGridView`'s Official document on the following link:

[CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)